# Generate Explicit Interface code from Inferred TypeScript Interface

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, refactoring

Let's say, I have a code snippet:

```
const todo = {name: "Learn Some TS", isDone: true}
```

How can I **automatically** generate the following:

```
interface TodoInterface {
    name: string
    isDone: Boolean
}
```

Looking for any tools where I can get the interface from code snippets.  It doesn't necessarily have to solve this exact scenario.

Comment: I guess webstrom can do that

Comment: I mean, what I do is use IntelliSense's quickinfo when hovering over `todo` in my IDE (VS code will do this, for example), which displays `const todo: {   name: string;   isDone: boolean; }`, which I can then copy and paste.  Don't know if this counts as "automatically" or not.  If so I can write up an answer.

Comment: Aaaah I see.  Hover over variable todo, and then you can copy/paste from the IntelliSense's quickinfo

Comment: The method mentioned by @jcalz is probably the most accessible, but just be aware that it will truncate long types (unions with many members, interfaces with many properties, etc.), indicating the truncation with `...`. Depending on the complexity of your data, you might be interested in third-party tools such as [quicktype](https://quicktype.io/typescript).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the IDEs I use (VSCode and [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play)), I hover the pointer over the value whose type I want to capture.  This brings up [IntelliSense quick info](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense) describing the type, and you can copy and paste that.

For

```
const todo = { name: "Learn Some TS", isDone: true }
```

The provided info looks like this

```
/* const todo: {
    name: string;
    isDone: boolean;
} */
```

which can be copied, pasted, and modified to give you

```
interface TodoInterface {
  name: string;
  isDone: boolean;
}
```

Supplemental screen capture demo:

[image: Screen capture of copy/pasting IntelliSense quick info]

---

Note that your compiler options may end up truncating long types. For example, imagine you have this type:

```
type SomeFiltered<T extends any[]> =
  T extends [infer F, ...infer R] ? [F, ...SomeFiltered<R>] | SomeFiltered<R> : []
```

It takes a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) and produces a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all possible filtered versions of it.  Since each element can either be present or absent, you end up turning a tuple of  elements into a union of 2 tuples.  That's a lot.  So this

```
type LongType = SomeFiltered<["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]>
```

can be expected to have 32 union members.  With default compiler options, you will not see the full type with IntelliSense:

```
/*
type LongType = [] | ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"] | ["B", "C", "D", "E"] | ["C", "D", "E"] |
  ["D", "E"] | ["E"] | ["D"] | ["C"] | ["C", "E"] | ["C", "D"] | ["B"] | ["B", "D", "E"] |
  ["B", "E"] | ... 18 more ... | [...]
*/
```

See the `... 18 more ...` and `[...]` truncations.

You can disable such truncation by enabling [the `--noErrorTruncation` compiler flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noErrorTruncation). (It's a little bit of an unfortunate name, since it suppresses truncation of displayed type names everywhere, not just in error messages.)  Then you get this:

```
/* with --noErrorTruncation=true
type LongType = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"] | ["B", "C", "D", "E"] | ["C", "D", "E"] | 
  ["D", "E"] | ["E"] | [] | ["D"] | ["C", "E"] | ["C"] | ["C", "D"] | ["B", "D", "E"] | 
  ["B", "E"] | ["B"] | ["B", "D"] | ["B", "C", "E"] | ["B", "C"] | ["B", "C", "D"] | 
  ["A", "C", "D", "E"] | ["A", "D", "E"] | ["A", "E"] | ["A"] | ["A", "D"] | 
  ["A", "C", "E"] | ["A", "C"] | ["A", "C", "D"] | ["A", "B", "D", "E"] | 
  ["A", "B", "E"] | ["A", "B"] | ["A", "B", "D"] | ["A", "B", "C", "E"] | 
  ["A", "B", "C"] | ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
*/
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBFIBMQwLwwN4zAQwLYFMAuGAIgBl9sAnMGAZRAJgBU6SAaGASwgBFwicKgFd8MAL4BYAFAB6AFQxQkWPCTF0MmNqx5B0KlzABzANxadPfmEEAjECAA2lMOeniY82TJlGo+KgAzbGAxZkQQAEkwfyCQsU1pbRwCYgMjYwsrAWJ7JxcZKWkfaSgATwAHMQYCADEuR1j8BAAeZhh8AA9-MAQIGGwwMoBtAF0APlQLdq6evphho0CAmFrOADpNpZWAJVGYAH4FtZhN9Zr8esaA5pad8f2AH3pGS4am1vuYYjGS8qqYGRwMZmJUxGgLlcPi1hiQAIIcUgAIURJAAwqjeKiAKIkCYyBQwADuXCgAAsYABaSlgEDYqhUEBUZgiMDAbBQLjgFDBRwQfAyf5iIEmUEAtBjGDPWEIzgkFFyjFyrFy3FPBby1FK0gq0hqqUa7UkXUkfWPCywk1mjXWy14g2wjHqx04+3S9GYt0alHOzXK11PC1+vVes4wACMAA4YLgmWIw9KzqMZF4SoSSeSqTS6QymSzhGyOVywCgoCIBaUwYDgWLwRrZcitZ7VV7YQrSEara2Pf6W76u4GkjbW-3u0bbR7fZ3u+3jQGHcHTTO3UHZ1jfbPx8vFduO57fQ2ezr5+ahzLmyGDyf693D+uF4et1ed4PtOed-7n43e5eH6jZxOh4+n+cpriuZ7wv+TZ9iB357l+i7Tsm0heEAA)